# Nested Array of Object Data Transformation

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could anyone please guide me in how to create the below output. I need to create a graph using chart.js

I have 3 role like vos, voe, vod

The result which I get from the database is

```
const d = [{
  roleId: 1,
  role: 'vos',
  rating: 5,
  date: '2020-07-07',
},
{
  roleId: 3,
  role: 'voe',
  rating: 3,
  date: '2020-07-07',
},
{
  roleId: 1,
  role: 'vos',
  rating: 5,
  date: '2020-07-04',
},
{
  roleId: 1,
  role: 'vos',
  rating: 3,
  date: '2020-07-01',
}];
```

If I don't get the role for a specific date then need to add 0 ratings for it in a role array which it belongs. Could anyone please guide and explain. I always find it difficult to transform data.

output

```
{
 dates: ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-04', '2020-07-07'],
 vos: [3, 5, 5],
 vod: [0, 0, 0],
 voe: [0, 0, 3]
}
```

i am trying not sure how to go ahead.

```
const res = {
  label: [],
  vos: [],
  vod: [],
  voe: []
};
const newSet = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i += 1) {
  constnewSet.add(d[i]);
  const date = [...newSet];
  for (let j = 0; j < date.length; j += 1) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this: You build up a helper map-object containing the data grouped by the date. You then sort this object's keys resulting in an array sorted by the dates which you then can iterate and build up the resulting object:

```js
function groupData(data) {
  const dateMap = {};

  for (const entry of data) {
    if (!dateMap[entry.date]) {
      dateMap[entry.date] = { vos: 0, vod: 0, voe: 0 };
    }
    dateMap[entry.date][entry.role] = entry.rating;
  }

  const dates = Object.keys(dateMap).sort();
  const res = { dates: [], vos: [], vod: [], voe: [] };
  for (const date of dates) {
    res.dates.push(date);
    res.vos.push(dateMap[date].vos);
    res.vod.push(dateMap[date].vod);
    res.voe.push(dateMap[date].voe);
  }

  return res;
}
const d=[{roleId:1,role:'vos',rating:5,date:'2020-07-07',},{roleId:3,role:'voe',rating:3,date:'2020-07-07',},{roleId:1,role:'vos',rating:5,date:'2020-07-04',},{roleId:1,role:'vos',rating:3,date:'2020-07-01',},];
console.log(groupData(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer does the exact same as the [answer of eol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62776895/3982562) but doesn't hard-code the `vos`, `vod` and `voe` properties. For the explanation check out the linked answer.

```js
const roles = ['vos', 'vod', 'voe'];
const records = [
  { roleId: 1, role: 'vos', rating: 5, date: '2020-07-07' },
  { roleId: 3, role: 'voe', rating: 3, date: '2020-07-07' },
  { roleId: 1, role: 'vos', rating: 5, date: '2020-07-04' },
  { roleId: 1, role: 'vos', rating: 3, date: '2020-07-01' },
];

const ratings = {};
for (const { role, rating, date } of records) {
  if (!ratings[date]) {
    ratings[date] = Object.fromEntries(roles.map(role => [role, 0]));
  }
  ratings[date][role] = rating;
}

const dates = Object.keys(ratings).sort();
const result = Object.assign(
  { dates },
  Object.fromEntries(
    roles.map(role => [role, dates.map(date => ratings[date][role])])
  )
);

console.log(result);
```